# Oracle to SQL Server Migration Special Characters issue

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, migration, database-migration

I'm using SSMA to migrate a database from Oracle to SQL Server. I have a problem with special Characters like ß=ss and also Empty space like "Expression"  & "Expression ".

While migrating, SSMA recognize that ß = ss and "Expression"  is equal "Expression ", and it signals that there are some duplicates.

My question: Is there any configuration which prevent the migration tool from interpreting the string content

Comment: I don't know specifically, but normally thats a collation setting.

Comment: Sounds like your target SQL database is using a collation like `Latin1_General_CI_AS` if it considers `ß=ss`. As to the trailing white space issue - that's a data issue you need to clean up before migrating.

Comment: My target database is using Latin1_General_CI_AI. Which collation should be configured to bypass it or should I really clean all doubles??